# Hosting Yocto SSTATE_MIRROR over NFS on a busy Build Node - a bad idea?

Tags: yocto, nfs

In a distributed yocto build environment, is it a bad idea to host a global sstate cache (via SSTATE_MIRRORS) on a busy build node over NFS?

I have recently introduced SSTATE_MIRRORS in our yocto build configuration to try to further reduce yocto builds times on our "build nodes" (Jenkins agents in vSphere and developer workstations). Per [the manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SSTATE_MIRRORS), yocto will search SSTATE_MIRRORS for already-built artifacts if they are not found in the local sstate cache (SSTATE_DIR).

All build nodes have a local SSTATE_DIR, in which they cache build results. One of the build nodes (the first Jenkins agent) is designated as the "keeper of the global cache," and exports its local SSTATE_DIR as a r/o NFS share. The other build nodes mount this, and refer to it by SSTATE_MIRRORS in their build configurations. I thought I had a really good idea here and patted myself on the back.

Alas, I'm seeing a significant *increase* in build times after making the change.

Certainly I have a lot of troubleshooting and measuring to do before drawing any conclusions. We're using NFS v4, and for sure there's tuning to be done there. Also, I suspect the build node hosting the NFS share is intermittently very busy performing yocto builds itself (populating its hybrid local/global cache), leaving little CPU cycles for the kernel to manage NFS requests.

I'm wondering if others can offer advice based on their experiences implementing shared yocto sstate caches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what problems you are seeing with some profiling data, but I have a few observations and suggestions.

You are on the right track using NFS as the sstate cache between CI nodes, but I would recommend taking it one step further. Instead of having one node be the "keeper" of the sstate cache and having all the other node use it as a mirror, I would recommend having each node directly mount a common NFS share as `SSTATE_DIR`. This allows all the nodes to to read and write to the cache during their builds, and does a much better job of keeping it up to date with the required sstate objects. If you only have one node populating the cache, it is unlikely that it is going to contain all of the objects needed by the other builds.

Additionally, I would recommend that the NFS server be a persistent server instead of tied to a Jenkins agent. This gains you a few things:

1. It means that you can dedicate hardware resources to the cache without having them compete with an ongoing Jenkins build
2. You can put a simple HTTP server front end that serves up the cache files. Doing this allows your developer workstations to set that HTTP server as their `SSTATE_MIRROR`, and thus directly benefit from the cache produced by your Jenkins nodes. If you've done this correctly, a developer should be able to replicate a build that was previously built by Jenkins entirely from sstate, which can save a *ton* of local build time. Even if you aren't exactly replicating a build Jenkins has done before, you still can usually pull a significant amount from sstate.

The final thing to check is if you have hash equivalence enabled. Hash equivalence is a build acceleration technology that allows the bitbake to detect when metadata changes to a recipe that would normally cause it to rebuild would result in the same output as a previously built sstate object, and instead of building it restore it from sstate. This feature is enable by default starting with Yocto 3.0 (codename zeus). If you do not have a hash equivalence server running in your infrastructure, bitbake will start a local server for the duration of your build. However, this can cause some issues when working in a distributed environment like your Jenkins nodes, because hash equivalence is highly dependent on the contents of the sstate cache. If each node is running it's own hash equivalence server locally, they can get diverging sstate hashes (particularly when the CI nodes are transient and the local hash equivalence database is lost), which can result in more sstate misses that is necessary. The solution to this is to either run a hash equivalence server (bitbake comes with one) and point all your CI nodes at it, or disable hash equivalence completely by setting: `BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER = "OEBasicHash"`.

Comment: Thanks so much, very insightful! One question about your point 1.. any particular reason you think HTTP would be superior to NFS here? Developers and Jenkins nodes could do either just as easily from my perspective. Im investigating the various shared filesystem solutions in VMware for the Jenkins nodes, which have 30Gbps internetworking throughput. Our devs only have 1Gbps connections to the SSTATE_MIRRORS (which will be in the vSphere cluster along with the Jenkinses) and I'm wondering how much of a bottle neck that is.

Comment: @timblaktu we use NFSv4 and it is very reliable. No problem whatsoever. The arch is also the same as yours. SSTATE_DIR for CI master and SSTATE_MIRROR for devs or other non privileged builds.

Comment: @timblaktu It is possible for developers to use the same NFS sstate cache as Jenkins. I think that typically this is not possible or ideal either because of bandwidth, disk space, network segmentation, or other factors, so I usually recommend an HTTP SSTATE_MIRRORS since it is mostly likely to give the best experience.

However, I've never run an NFS cache shared with developers, so I could be wrong on a few of these points. Feel free to try and let me know!

Comment: I wonder what ranges of iops performance is expected/reasonable for the storage volumes used for sstate_cache and sstate_mirrors? Do you know if the yocto project has any documentation or best practices published about this? I know that it will search local cache before the mirrors, and I assume that both require fast random access for searching the cache tree for files, and fast sequential reads for copying matches.

Comment: There is (normally) no "searching" of the cache that is done. Yocto is able to construct the exact path to the sstate object before it attempts to access it, so all the accesses are either path lookups or linear reads. This is why it can use HTTP as an sstate mirror, since there is no directory scanning over HTTP; you have to know the URL you want.

It does search the cache when you do `-c cleansstate`, but that's not the normal workflow